# How can I access my EC2 instance with the public IP which is running an IIS web server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2

I have an IIS server running in an EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 instance on port 5000. When I try to access this from a different machine or network using the public IP of the instance, it doesn't allow me to connect.

I have searched all over and looked at similar issues with no success.

Many people say it is to do with security groups and opening ports on the instance but as far as I am aware, I have done this. I have triple checked the security group that the instance is using and here are my rules

[image]

I have confirmed that the application is working using curl to get a response from the server and that seems to be working fine and produces the correct output.

`telnet localhost 5000` also works.

With the ICMP rule added to the security group I am able to ping the server successfully using the public IP.

---

The `ufw` is disabled.

I have tried adding the ports to the iptables and the applications seem to be listening on the correct ports.

Iptables:

[image: Iptables]

[image]

---

Webserver launch config:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:50135/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/test",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the applicationUrl also but this didn't seem to do anything.

Does anyone know why I can't access the server from the public IP address?

Comment: Is the IIS server bound to the public IP?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR I will double check this

Comment: Share output of 'iptables -L'

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR I have tried binding to both public ip and localhost but neither work.

Comment: @EytanAvisror I have added the image to the post

Comment: Try flusing all the rules - iptables -F
Are you getting timeouts on the client side?

Comment: @EytanAvisror Just done that. Now I can't see the rules when I do `iptables -L` if that's supposed to happen. And I just receive "refused to connect" in the browser.

Comment: Can you share your webserver configuration file?

Comment: @EytanAvisror updated. I don't believe I've touched this but this config is from the ASP NET Core project template. I am running the production build though using `dotnet publish` if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: I think the problem is that your webserver is bound to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0 or the public ip address. try "applicationUrl": "http ://0.0.0.0:5000/"

Comment: @EytanAvisror this doesn't seem to work, unless this config isn't being used. After running `netstat -tulpn`, it still says `127.0.0.1` and when running the application it says it's listening `localhost:5000`

Comment: Not very familiar with IIS for Ubuntu, but there should be a way somehow for you to change the local address to 0.0.0.0 / the public ip address.
Did you restart the webserver after committing the change? Another option would be to set up a reverse proxy from something like ngnix or apache that receives traffic on port 80/443 and forwards to localhost:5000

Comment: Okay this is the issue. I have moved the entire project across to the instance and ran `dotnet run` from the project folder. This runs it in debug mode and uses this config file in my post and allows me to access it via the public IP. However, I need to find out how to edit the url generated for the production build.

Comment: @EytanAvisror Managed to change the production url, thanks for pointing this out. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it if I can :). Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does "doesn't allow me to connect." mean - what are you doing and what response do you get? No one can troubleshoot an issue without an actual explanation of the issue./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection refused means the client is able to connect, but the server listener refused it, `netstat -an` showed the dotnet process listening on 127.0.0.1:5000, which means it is only accessible from the local machine.
Solution is to bind the local address to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost by changing the value of applicationUrl in the config file and restarting the web service.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS EC2, you should bind your application to the **Private IP** of your EC2 instance.

1. Do ***ipconfig*** command from command prompt and get the private
   ip.
2. **Configure your application to bind to that Private IP**
3. Restart IIS
4. Ensure that Security Group of your EC2 instance has an inbound
   rule allowing port 5000 to be accessed from *"Anywhere"*